# Как скопировать текст в буфер обмена при клике на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно скопировать текст из `p` тега при клике на кнопку, как это сделать? В гугле непонятные для меня способы, может есть способ по-проще?

```js
var mail = document.querySelector('p');
var button = document.querySelector('div');
button.onclick = function (event) {
 
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>email</p>
<div>copy</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74353/discussion-on-question-by-uzi-no-uzi--------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var mail = document.querySelector('p').textContent;
var button = document.querySelector('div');
button.onclick = function (event) {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", mail);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.querySelector('INPUT').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert(mail);
     document.querySelector("INPUT").style.display="none";
    
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input{

}
```

```html
<p>email</p>
<div>copy</div>
```

Comment: Так мне надо в буфер обмена скопировать, а не вывести alerto'm :)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi сделал

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi так?